# Using PerCall, are assemblies loaded once in WCF or per call?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a `WCF service` that is configured as `PerCall`. Each call sets up an `Entity Framework` connection to a back-end database and will load a sleuth of assemblies.

How does loading of assemblies work in `WCF`, will they be loaded per call, or once per lifetime of the service?

Will there be any benefits of switching to `PerSession` instead in this regard, or is this a non-issue?

Comment: Are the assemblies loaded in the constructor (or by calls in the constructor)?

Comment: Some assemblies are loaded on the fly others was referenced at compile time and are listed in the app.config

Comment: Then I think you are OK but not sure enough to post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one copy of the dll's are loaded.

The difference is in the instances of the objects in memory and connections to the database.

For example if your solution has a single dll that makes a connection to the database. Assume the server has just rebooted. Per Call:

- Call 1 comes in the DLL will be loaded into memory and JIT compiled
- An instance of the service will be created
- A connection to the database will be created
- Then this call completes
- The connection will be releaced to the connection pool
- The instance of the service will be disposed and the garbage collection will clean it up.
- Then call 2 and 3 come in at the same time
- The dll is loaded and JIT compiled therefore no work here
- 2 instances will be created for 2 and 3
- One connection will be retrieved from the connection pool
- One connection will be created
- Then the calls complete
- The connections will be releaced to the connection pool
- The instances of the service will be disposed and the garbage collection will clean it up.

Allways a single copy of DLL that is JIT compiled on first hit.

- Per Call, an instance per call that is disposed at end of call.
- Per Session, an instance per session that is disposed when the session expires
- Single, a single instance

Comment: Thank you! So you are saying that only during the first call is the assembly loaded and JIT compiled?

Comment: Thanks again, one more question pops up, is this true regardless of how you host your service? i.e. either self-hosting, windows service or iis?

Comment: Yes, how it is hosted will not affect this

Comment: What about IIS hosting? Potentially couldn't a reload occur if the service is idle after 20min, unless this is disabled?

Comment: Yes, but it would be the same if a windows service restarted. We normally configure a IIS App Pool to restart once per day.